# Rank one linear operator on open unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose that $X, Y$ be two normed space and $T:X\to Y$ be a linear operator such a way that $Rank(T) =1$. Suppose that $B,D$ are unit balls of $X, T(X)$, respectively. Prove that
$$T(B) = ||T||D$$

The main problem for me is proving that $||T||D \subset T(B)$. Since $Rank(T) =1$ therefore we could assume that there is $y_0$ in $im(T)$ such that for any x in $X$ there is $f(x)$ with $T(x) = f(x)y_0$

Comment: Is there any specific norm definition for $||T||$ or it is usual norm operator? I mean, norm operator with different definition

Comment: For me, a rank 1 operator has an entire range that is one dimensional. Unless the target space is one dimensional, there's no way it's image could contain a ball. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, You are right. I will edit it now. $D$ is a unit ball of $T(X)$. @JonathanZ

Comment: Okay, now what have you tried, and what part is giving you problems?

Comment: Also, your definition of norm in your comment seems off - how can you talk about $T(D)$ when $D$ is a subset of the range? Can you tell us where this question came from?

Comment: It was typo, sorry. $||T|| = \inf\{r\geq 0 | T(B)\subset rD\}$. I wanted to prove a norm equation and I reached to a point that I needed to prove this equality, if it is true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being of rank one, $T$ is indeed of the form
$$\forall x\in X\quad T(x)=f(x)y_0$$
for some unit vector $y_0\in Y$ and some linear functional $f$ on $X$, having therefore the same norm as $T.$

Your problem becomes to prove that for every $f\in X'$, with norm $r,$ we have
$$f(B)=(-r,r),$$
where $B$ is the open unit ball in $X.$ More precisely, since we agree that $f(B)\subset(-r,r)$, the task is to prove $f(B)\supset(-r,r).$

So, let $t\in(-r,r).$ Since
$$|t|<r=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in B\},$$
there exists $x\in B$ such that $|t|<|f(x)|.$ The vector
$$u:=\frac t{f(x)}x.$$
satisfies $f(u)=t$ and $$\|u\|=\frac{|t|}{|f(x)|}\|x\|<\|x\|<1,$$
which ends the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect, clear, helpful, friendly response!